# Outlook randomly freezes while composing a new email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Outlook 2007 (Exchange mailbox) randomly freezes on an XP SP3 machine.  Maybe after a few minutes, maybe after a whole day.  It seems to be completely random but it ***always*** happens while in the middle of typing an email.  We have left it for 30 minutes to check that it was not just busy doing something, still dead as a doorknob.

Task Manager reports nothing out of the ordinary in terms of CPU or memory usage.

What I have tried:

- New Outlook mail profile
- Office Diagnostics, no problems found
- Ran Outlook in safe mode with no addons
- Checked for any Office service packs (was already on the latest) and updates

What else can I do to try and fix this?

Note - there is a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/5870/what-can-cause-an-outlook-2007-email-to-suddenly-become-uneditable-while-composin) but in my case Outlook locks up completely.

Comment: This is a bit random, but do you have skype running? I remember that that was a problem in a place I was working in.

Comment: No no, random is good.  Unfortunately no Skype though.

Comment: I think you should try and rule out that any other program is interfering with it. Does it freeze up if you do a restart and the first program you open is outlook?

Comment: sorry for the unrelated comment.  when you vote to close a question as a duplicate, please try to leave a comment with a link to the duplicate (if there's not one already).  just a simple *"duplicate: http://<link"* is enough.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a boring resolution to this.  We eventually created a new user profile from scratch, which resolved all of the problems.  At least, that's what we're hoping...

Answer (score 0):

What version of Outlook 2007? With or without the SP1 for office 2007?

I know the service pack that came out for office 2007 made a lot of performance improvements. Go to the office or windows updates site and download the latest updates for office/outlook 2007.

Comment: Already on the latest service pack......... which is SP2 :-)  The full version title is Office Professional 2007 OEM.

Comment: Didnt remember off the top of my head if it was SP1 or SP2. Sorry bout that.

Another thing I can suggest is the following:

Start>Run

then type:

outlook.exe /cleanprofile