# Tip for when Outlook freezes while composing messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, freeze

My copy of Outlook 2013 (32-bit on Win10 Enterprise 64-bit, connected to Exchange Server 2010 SP3) fairly often freezes while composing messages. If you look at Task Manager, Outlook is using about 30% of CPU while frozen.

I have waited up to 30 minutes to see if it would thaw, but it never has. As a result, I have lost unsaved drafts of messages. Even if the save interval is just a couple of minutes, it can be a lot of lost work.

My answer is provided below.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have found a couple of suggestions for fixing the problem, which I will outline at the end.

My tip, though, is this: If Outlook freezes while composing, go to the task bar and right-click on each icon that represents a draft message. Click on "Close window" ...

[image: Close email draft window]

... and Outlook will display the dialog asking whether you want to save your changes ...

[image]

If you then click "Yes," your changes will be saved in your Drafts folder. Repeat for each message you're composing.

Unfortunately, it does not cause Outlook to wake up. You still have to close Outlook via the Task Manager and restart it. But you haven't lost your work.

Other possible solutions:

1. [Freeze caused by nickname cache](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3163997/outlook-freezes-when-composing-a-new-email-or-replying): I have been playing with this,
   and so far I have reduced my cache size from 1,000 to 600, and the
   freezes continue. I'll continue decreasing the size for a while to
   see if that helps.
2. [Freeze caused by damaged user profile](https://superuser.com/questions/107594/outlook-randomly-freezes-while-composing-a-new-email): Try
   and see if it helps. I did not bother with this because my
   experience is that changing user profiles has not helped with
   anything else.
3. [Freeze caused by corrupt local files](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/740243-outlook-2010-crashes-when-creating-or-replying-to-an-email): This is
   said to apply only in cached Exchange mode, but I'm not using that
   mode. Try it if you are.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of Outlook freeze when using an Exchange mailbox is the Online Exchange mode. You may first check whether you are using online Exchange mode, try switching to cached Exchange mode to see whether this issue persists.

Also have a look at this article: [How to troubleshoot performance issues in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2695805/how-to-troubleshoot-performance-issues-in-outlook). It listed several possible causes for this issue.

Comment: I went through the article's list briefly. The performance issues did not seem to apply. My folders have fewer items than the problematic levels mentioned. I noticed also that both cached and online modes can have problems. I also have some offline PST folders, but even though some of them are large, they are less than 1GB (the article says <5GB should be okay). The article focused on performance improvement and did not mention actual freezing of the program.